# Load report failed in crystal report?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am using crystal report for reporting and facing the below issue in recent 2 days.
Please find the piece of code and error message what I have received in the below. It would be really helpful if I get a support from you.

```
**string strReportName = string.Empty;
            ReportDocument repDoc = new ReportDocument();
              strReportName = "NHCADCoversheet.rpt";

            string repFilePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("Reports\\" + strReportName);
            repDoc.Load(repFilePath);
            repDoc.SetDataSource(dsCoversheet);
            repDoc.SetParameterValue("taxYear", strTaxYear);
            repDoc.SetParameterValue("County", county);
            repDoc.SetParameterValue("RecentSaleDate", recentSaleDate);
            repDoc.SetParameterValue("ClientFlags", ClientSettelmentFlag);
            repDoc.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, strReportExportPath + "\\Coversheet_1.PDF");
            repDoc.Close();
            repDoc.Dispose();**
```

Error Message:

The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached.
Load report failed.
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
at Noncorecoversheet.SalesPrint(DataSet dsCoversheet, String strReportExportPath, String strTaxYear, String ClientSettelmentFlag) in d:\Vivek Workspace\FilePrep_Offline_2023\SmartHCADAutomationV2_BKP_02_May_2023\SmartHCADAutomationV2\PathfinderApps\App_Code\Class\NonCore\Noncorecoversheet.cs:line 443

I have increased the job print limit in the registry settings.
I have reinstall the crystal reports in my development machine and IIS server.